# jQuery validation-does not form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation, jquery-plugins

I am using jQuery validation plugin.It validates successfully but after correct submission form not submitting.

Here is the code:

```
jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
          debug: true,
          success: "valid"
        });
        $("#myform").validate({
          rules: {
            ip: {
                required: true,
                maxlength: 15,
                minlength: 11
            },
            assert_code: {
                required: true,
                maxlength: 17,
                minlength: 17
            }            
          }
        });

 form example
      <form id = "myform" method = "post" >
      <input type = "text" name = "ip" id = "ip"/>
      <input type = "text" name = "assert_cpde" id = "assert_code"/>
      <input type = "submit" name = "submit" />
      </form>
```

Comment: _after correct submission form not submitting_ show us the code please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I need to write code like this.and its done!!

```
$(function() {
    $("#myform").validate({
      rules: {
        ip: {
            required: true,
            maxlength: 15,
            minlength: 11
        },
        assert_code: {
            required: true,
            maxlength: 17,
            minlength: 17
        }            
      }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have typo in `assert_code` name (you wrote `assert_cpde`)

Correct version:

```
<form id = "myform" method = "post" >
    <input type = "text" name = "ip" id = "ip"/>
    <input type = "text" name = "assert_code" id = "assert_code"/>
    <input type = "submit" name = "submit" />
</form>
```